# R: for loop executed only for the last list element

Tags: r, list, for-loop

I have a dataset (mags) of samples from different phyla and classes which I want to sort.
First, I created an empty list containing as many empty data frames as I have different phyla.
In principle this is working, but one can already see the problem in the output.

```
Phylum <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")
Mags <- data.frame(Phylum=c("a", "a", "b", "c", "d", "d", "d"), 
                   Class=c("A1", "A2", "B1", "C1", "D1", "D2", "D3"))

erg <- list()

for (i in length(Phylum)) {
  erg[[i]] <- data.frame(i)
}

names(erg) <- Phylum
```

Afterwards, I want to sort the samples. Which phylum contains which classes.
The classes should be written into the data frames, while each phylum has his own data frame in the list.

```
for (i in length(Phylum)){
  erg[[i]] <- data.frame(unique(Mags$Class[Mags$Phylum == Phylum[i]]))
  
}
```

In the output, it worked only for the last element of the list. But I can't figure out why.

To make sure that the function in principle does what I want to, I tried it without a for loop.

```
erg[[1]] <- data.frame(unique(Mags$Class[Mags$Phylum == Phylum[1]]))
erg[[2]] <- data.frame(unique(Mags$Class[Mags$Phylum == Phylum[2]]))
erg[[3]] <- data.frame(unique(Mags$Class[Mags$Phylum == Phylum[3]]))
erg[[4]] <- data.frame(unique(Mags$Class[Mags$Phylum == Phylum[4]]))
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you copy paste what the current output looks like and what you want after your loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should replace `length(Phylum)` by `seq_along(Phylum)`.

```r
for (i in seq_along(Phylum)){ # or 1:length(Phylum)
  erg[[i]] <- data.frame(unique(Mags$Class[Mags$Phylum == Phylum[i]]))
}
```

`length(Phylum)` is equal to 4 but you need 1 to 4.

Comment: or `1:length(Phylum)`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm glad it was such a small mistake :D

Comment: That's ok... sometimes these small mistakes take hours to debug. also, you can use the Rstudio debugger.

Comment: @arashHaratian I think *"tidier"* is the wrong adjective for `seq_along`. The main reason people like to use `seq_along()` is that if the input happens to have length 0 you won't end up with a error because your loop goes over `1, 0`, so *"more robust"* or *"more stable"* would be good adjectives.